# Image not shown, image insertion markdown not interpreted

Tags: support, design, markdown, images

Tried to add an image to an answer of mine, but the image doesn't show in preview and it doesn't show after the question is saved either.

Instead of the image, the un-interpreted markdown for the image is shown `[![enter image description here][1]][1]` appears in both during preview time and after publishing.

I had to delete the line.

What is it happening here. the picture's address markdown continues inside the source and is this one:   `[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3JGL.png`

If you copy and paste the URL into a browser tab, you can see the image without problems.

[image]

Comment: It works for me. What is special in the markdown surrounding that image markdown? Are you inside code markup? Any other open but not closed html tag?

Comment: @rene Nothing. I tried to insert the image after a paragraph and before the beginning of a block of code `~~~` leaving black lines before and after.

Comment: @rene Some days ago I inserted an image in one of my answers with no problem.

Comment: I tried it in the sandbox and it shows for me: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327693/158100

Comment: I'd check first for userscripts that might cause such weird problems. Disable all userscripts and try again. This includes also things like adblockers, and anything in the browser that can mess with JS/HTML on the pages.

Comment: @rene **Using HTML IMG tag worked!** In this question I added a screen capture of how the image is not rendered in the preview and the markdown is visible in the preview instead. Curious enough I added the screen capture in this meta question using markdown with no problem.

Comment: I can only reproduce this if there is a codeblock that starts with a code-fench but isn't closed as such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your revision [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/a87fb3d9-e8bb-4d94-822d-02bcee91d939/view-source) you've started a code block with a code fence.

But you never closed it. Therefore the needed markdown reference for the image becomes part of the code block. If a reference isn't found, the link or image isn't rendered.

![Image?][1]

If you definitely don't want to close your code block with a code fence, move the reference before the start of your code fence like I've shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yj9f.png).

Or move the URL directly to the image:

[image]

```
 ![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3JGL.png)
```

Here is the code block with the starting code fence, but no ending one ...

```
public class CSharpRulez {
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3JGL.png
```

Answer (score 5):

In [this revision](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/414905/4) of your answer the linking part of your image ( [1]: ) ended up in the code block making the editor unable to render your image as it didn't interpret the hyperlink as such. Make sure to properly indent your code and to close code fences at the end.